# Using python how do I click a button to scrape the content hidden

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hello I wrote a function using selenium to click the "advisor" button so that I can scrape the table hidden. when I run it my chrome driver successfully opens and visits the page.. but the button does not get clicked.
I hope, you guys help me to figure this out?
NOTE: I am new to scraping techniques. also please let me know If this can be done with `bs4`. Here is a code:

```
def scrapper():
    u = "https://teqatlas.com/products-and-services/0chain"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    # stop load after a timeout
    try:
        browser.get(u)
    except TimeoutException:
        browser.execute_script("window.stop();")
        
    button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="o5ph61-3 eBqrHG"]')
    if button:
        button.click()

scrapper()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://teqatlas.com/products-and-services/0chain")

btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.o5ph61-3.faMQuX").click()
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/3a534be2e1b57833535301c169d57d67/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: let me install firefox, sorry

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar you can use Chrome, Edge, Firefox and Safari. check [docs](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to download your preferred driver.

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar you need to put `geckodriver` within your `Python` installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I am also new to selenium. I changed find_element_by_xpath to find_element_by_class_name here though.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
def business_description_scrapper():
    u = "https://teqatlas.com/products-and-services/0chain"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    # stop load after a timeout
    try:
        browser.get(u)
    except TimeoutException:
        browser.execute_script("window.stop();")

    button = browser.find_element_by_class_name("o5ph61-3.eBqrHG")
    if button:
        actions = ActionChains(browser)
        actions.click(button).perform()

business_description_scrapper()
```

I tested it and the button got clicked.

Comment: thank you so much, I will implement the code and will loet you know the result

Comment: Does it find the button and unable to click? Or unable to find button?

Comment: a button got clicked but it was not the "advisories" button..

Comment: @Sabbir How about now?

Comment: this is the most troubling thing.. no error messages show up

Comment: what does print(button) print?

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e349ae65debe0273664129786343d911", element="de9df767-f37e-401b-8fa8-96cf55d4b345")>

Answer (score 0):

The xpath that you are using is incorrect. Please pick the below xpath to click on the button:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Advisories']"))).click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: thank you so much, I will implement the code and will loet you know the result

Comment: @SabbirTalukdar please pick the updated ans, i have added explicit wait in this.